# How to render 3d video for cardboard in android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm trying to find out if there are any examples how to play 3D video for cardboard in android. I have a 3D video and need my app to play in cardboard. I'm not sure if the SDK has support and couldn't figure it out as there is very less documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. For me only solution that worked is to use that is described at [HERE](http://immersivetechblog.foundry45.com/2015/07/31/implementing-360-video-in-unity-for-gear-vr-and-cardboard/). Had to Use unity with a plugin to play video on movietexture.

Without using the unity plugin [Easy Movie Texture plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032) I couldn't find any easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is not very easy. I think the problem is not about Google Cardboard, but about Unity itself. It is not easy to add any kind of video to Unity. If you are able to open a normal video within the Unity game, I think that 3D video will work too.

Check the docs about how to configure it for Android: http://docs.unity3d.com/es/current/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html

I tried to add a video to an older version of Unity. Unity crashed. I did the conversion manually. I wrote the explanation here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/997663/unity-video-import-bug.html

Answer (score 1):

I think this:

[Google Cardboard SDK (Software Developement Kit)](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/)

Will help you to build apps that display 3D scenes with binocular rendering, track and react to head movements, and interact with apps through magnet input.

also you can easily adapt an existing Unity 3D app for virtual reality or build your own VR experience from scratch.

Comment: Don't know if the question is understood, but I want to know how to implement this video player?

Comment: do you mean recording

Comment: No, it's the player implementation? Is there way I can just pass video path and play the video? Edited the question with more details.

Comment: SDK doesn't help much in how to render a 3d video. Unity seems to be the way. But couldn't find success. Looking for ideas and stuck...